# Identity Error on UserName in Moq

Tags: asp.net, moq, xunit

I try to set an user object property in my unit test. This property is correctly passed to a custom user validator and was verified to be set during debugging. However, the `IdentityResult` still shows a blank property error.

I have this custom user validator:

```
public class CustomUserValidator : UserValidator<AppUser>
    {
        public override async Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(UserManager<AppUser> userManager, AppUser user)
        {
            //Here, the user.UserName property is set from the unit test, but the result still has an error for a blank UserName property
            IdentityResult result = await base.ValidateAsync(userManager, user);

            List<IdentityError> errors = result.Succeeded ? new List<IdentityError>() : result.Errors.ToList();

            if (user.Email.ToLower().EndsWith("@myDomain.com"))
            {
                return await Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Success);
            }
            else
            { 
                errors.Add(new IdentityError
                {
                    Code = "EmailDomainError",
                    Description = "Only myDomain.com email addresses are allowed"
                });
            }

            return errors.Count == 0 ? IdentityResult.Success : IdentityResult.Failed(errors.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

And I'm trying to use Moq and xUnit to create a test for the domain check on the email:

```
[Fact]
        public async void Validate_User_Email()
        {
            //Arrange
            var userManager = GetMockUserManager();
            var customVal = new CustomUserValidator();
            var user = Mock.Of<AppUser>(m => m.UserName == "joe" && m.Email == "joe@example.com");

            //Act
            //try to validate the user 
            IdentityResult result = await customVal.ValidateAsync(userManager.Object, user);

            //Assert
            //demonstrate that there are  errors present
            List<IdentityError> errors = result.Succeeded ? new List<IdentityError>() : result.Errors.ToList();

            //Here there are 2 errors, one for a blank UserName and one (expected) error for the email address
            Assert.Equal(1, errors.Count);
        }
```

Comment: is UserName a virtual property?

Comment: @Nkosi No, UserName is inherited from `IdentityUser`

Comment: Actually if it from `IdentityUser` then it is in fact virtual property. Just checked. Ok looking into your example.

Comment: @Nkosi ah, ok, sorry about my ignorance :-)

Comment: That said why are you mocking the AppUser, why not just create an instance and set the property values. I can understand mocking the manager, but the app user is just a model.

Comment: I am just beginning to delve into Moq and actually have been unsure when Mock'ing is appropriate. I don't have the code in front of me, I will try it out with a straight instance when I get a chance

Comment: ok cool. let me know how it goes.

Comment: Also no need to do this `return await Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Success);` you can just do `return IdentityResult.Success;` and you test should be `async Task` and not `async void`

Comment: @Nkosi I made the unit test return `Task` and changed the mocking of `AppUser` to just making an instance of the object, but the issue remains. I've tried different user names in the unit test and get the same error